# Generalized Hebbian Algorithm in ruby or python

Tags: python, ruby, neural-network

Have you a Generalized Hebbian Algorithm written in ruby or python?
I have it implemented from [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Hebbian_Algorithm) article, but it computes crazy large numbers.

This is the formula in ruby:

`@alpha * out[j] * (input[i] - out[j] * sum(@koef.times.map{|k| @weights[k][i] * out[k]}))  = -2.97697080169534e+15`

Is this wrong?
thx

Comment: Is this for your homework?  If so, please include the [homework] tag.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Hebbian_Algorithm) has all the formulas that you need. These can be implemented in python or ruby. Sadly, I can't afford the time to do that right now (I wish I could, though. This seems like fun).

Comment: Don't post code in a comment.  Please post code by **updating** your question so we can read it.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, you have `out[j]` once too much. Try:

```
@alpha*out[j]*(input[i] - sum(@koef.times.map{|k| @weights[k][i] * out[k]}))
```

Also, notice that alpha should be [decreasing with time](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.128.6893).